# How can i dynamically change title of input type file?

Tags: html, css, file-upload, input

I wanted to implement a different type of input file, so i used a css and html option of changing the default one. So i have the following html code:

```
<div class="fileinputs">&nbsp;
<input type="file" class="file" id="file" name="file" title="There aren't any files chosen yet." style="width:270px;"/>
<div class="fakefile">
<input tyle="button" name="button" value="Choose the file you want (click)" />
</div>
</div>
```

Then, the CSS code:

```
div.fileinputs {position: relative;}
div.fakefile {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1;
             }
input.file {
            position: relative;
            text-align: right;
            -moz-opacity:0 ;
            filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 2;
           }
```

Everything looks fine, when i mouse hover the input, it shows me the title i wrote in html. But i want it to change after i select a file, to show the name of file i have chosen. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to get the filename consistently with javascript and some parsing, but you should go away and research that yourself and come back if you can't get it working.

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes, i asked this question because i really needed an answer. If i could find out somehow else, i wouldn't have written it here. :) but thanks.

Comment: Not my downvote but I would imagine it is because you haven't shown any effort to solve the problem yourself. I suggested to look into using javascript, but now someone has done the work for you (even though you didn't tag javascript/JQuery you seem happy with an answer that uses them) so you don't have to do anything for yourself... this is not the way forward in life

Comment: @musefan I understand what you're trying to say, I do that almost all the time, but now I wasn't able to find something so I asked. Isn't that a way of learning, too? :)

Comment: And by the way, I didn't tagged javascript or jquery because in my question was nothing with that kind of code. If i would have done that I would have also got a downvote..so whatever :)

Comment: If you had identified the fact this was a javascript requirement (which it is) then you wouldn't have been punished for tagging it as so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/xeRtT/)**

**JS**:

```
 $('input').change(function(){
       $(this).attr('title',($(this).val()));
    });
```

Comment: Try this for showing only  file name ,not showing the full path ..http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/y4Lff/

Comment: Thanks again, that was also something i needed @Manoj.